# How can I sort a class using an array? - swift 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, tableview

I've a class called "cars":

```
car1 = [name: "ferrari", color: "black", size: "small" ]
car2 = [name: "Lamborghini", color: "orange", size: "small" ]
car3 = [name: "Audi", color: "black", size: "big" ]
car4 = [name: "fiat", color: "yellow", size: "small" ]
car5 = [name: "ferrari", color: "red", size: "medium" ]
```

and made a list of them:

```
list = [car1,car2,car3,car4]
```

and now I want to sort/filter this list.

If I try filtering it using a string, everything works fine:

```
let searchtext = "Audi"
filteredlist = list.filter({ $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) })
      --> filteredlist = [car3]   //result
```

but I want to use an array, so them I could have more results shown. Something like filtering by  more than one color (similar to an "or" condition in an "if statement").

I've tried the same struct (but of course didn't work):

```
let searchtext = ["black","red"]
filteredlist = list.filter({ $0.color.contains(searchText) })
    --> filteredlist = [car1,car3,car5]  //expected, got compilation error instead
```

I'm having these errors:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') to expected argument type 'String'  
Instance method 'contains' requires that '[String]' conform to 'StringProtocol'
```

I can think in 2 solutions (that aren't the ideal ones) to solve this need:

1 - create a while/for function and filter the list for each element of the searchtext array and unite everything in the end (not recommended because I will have to read the list 'n' times )

**update:stupid way**

```
var i = 0
var listapp: [Item] = []
while i < searchtext.count {
    listapp.append(contentsOf: list.filter({ $0.tipo.contains(searchtext[i]) }))
    i += 1
}
list = listapp
```

2 - manually filtering the list using 'if','or','while' instead of using list.filter function

Comment: You can use AND and OR when filtering `list.filter { ($0.color == "black" || $0.color == "red") && $0.name.lowercased() == "audi" }`

Comment: I don't know how many possibilities I have. It's an user input

Comment: You can write any amount of code that you want in the filter function. The opening and closing curly bracket need not be on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other way round:

```
let searchtext = ["black","red"]
filteredlist = list.filter({ searchtext.contains($0.color) })
```

Comment: You won't find `darkred` this way. The original version would do it.

Comment: Perfection in one line!

Answer (score 1):

A double `contains` should do it:

```
let searchText = ["black", "red"].map { $0.lowercased() }
filteredlist = list.filter { item in
   let color = item.color.lowercased()
   return searchText.contains { text in color.contains(text) }
}
```